# Search for file existence

Tags: filenames

I have a .txt file with a set of file names and I wanted to check the existence of those files in a directory.

```
cat file list.txt
File1
File2
File3
```

My script should check if these files exists in the directory or not.

Comment: With the `xargs` program from GNU coreutils: `xargs -d '\n' ls -d -- >/dev/null <list.txt` will print an error message to stderr for each line which doesn't contain an existing filename, and only exit with a 0 status if all the files were found.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to indicate what you already tried and where you ran into problems. That way contributors can understand what tools you have available/are familiar with, and you can avoid receiving proposed solutions that you already know won't work.

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh`:

```
dir=/some/dir
list_file=/path/to/file.list

list=( ${(f)"$(<$list_file)"} )
existing=( $dir/*(ND:t) )
files_in_list_that_exist=( ${list:*existing} )
files_in_list_that_dont_exist=( ${list:|existing} )
```

Existence in that case is determined by reading the contents of the `$dir`ectory, to which you need *read* permission (not necessarily *search* permission).

With any POSIX-like shell, you could also do:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
  if [ -e "$dir/$file" ] || [ -L "$dir/$file" ]; then
    found=yes
  else
    found=no
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "$file: $found"
done < "$list_file"
```

Here, find existence is determined using the `lstat()` system call (or variation thereof) on the files themselves, for which you need *search* permission to the `$dir`ectory, (not necessarily *read* permission).